# Chrome drag and drop download links

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

In Chrome, I used to be able to take a link to a file and just drag to a folder on my system.  Chrome would then download whatever resource was at the URL for the link and put it into the folder dropped into.

This was particularly handy when using Gmail.  If there was an attachment, I could just click and drag it into a folder, and Chrome would download it for me to the correct place.

Now I have to hit download, and then drag from the download bar when it is finished.

Has this feature been removed?  Is there any way to bring it back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug with the latest version of Chrome. I found that you can still drag and drop from the download bar however, not sure how much that will help though.

Comment: Have you seen a bug report for it?  I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: @brad I found two reports for it [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/gmail/thread?tid=774772d325026c75&hl=en "first report") and [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=48eb070a909f7394&hl=en "second report").